# How can I adjust the size of tcolorbox so that they fill the page without blank?

Tags: tcolorbox, includegraphics, vspace

I'm using tcolorbox in order to make exercises.
In these boxes, I regularly include images with `\includegraphics`, and also a vspace at the bottom so that the student can take notes. The exercises are of very variable size, some occupying an entire page, others barely one fifth of the page height.
Due to the unbreakable images and vspace, I often have page breaks leaving relatively large blanks between the boxes.
I guess there is no proper solution for this problem, except manually checking the position of exercices and potentially adjusting the size of images so that the breaks are more or less natural ? Or would there be some gizmo in Latex that could arrange the order of the boxes so that the breaks occur naturally ?

Besides, I've been using `\vspace{<size> plus <size> minus <size>`,  in hope that the spaces of the different boxes on the page would somewhat adjust so that the space between boxes is minimal. Nevertheless, I'm wondering if I'm not missing some code in order to make the vspace adjustable depending on the space left on the page? Moreover, I realize the `plus... minus...` only acts on the last box of my page, and does not take into account the possible existence of an adjustable space in the previous boxe(s) of the page. Is there any method to make Latex use variable height space accross different boxes in order to have regular space between the consecutive boxes ?

Below is a MWE just to make you understand the trouble, with normal space on page 2, and large spaces on pages 1 and 3 (I've been using `\tikz` to simulate an image). Changing the vspace on page 1 in order to have enough space to include the graphics that is now in the next page seems difficult because quite a lot of additional space is required. However, on page 3 it seems to me that it would be possible to reduce the size of the vspace on the upper box in order to have the graphics fit in the lower box. I understand that may require Latex to compile several times, and also take into account the next box when adjusting the height of the vspace. Is that possible ?

```
\documentclass[A4,12pt]{book}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins,breakable,xparse}
\NewTColorBox{exercise}{+O{}}{
enhanced,colframe=black,colback=black!10!white,breakable,
}

\begin{document}

\begin{exercise}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed non risus. Suspendisse lectus tortor, dignissim sit amet, adipiscing nec, ultricies sed, dolor. Cras elementum ultrices diam. Maecenas ligula massa, varius a, semper congue, euismod non, mi. Proin porttitor, orci nec nonummy molestie, enim est eleifend mi, non fermentum diam nisl sit amet erat. Duis semper. Duis arcu massa, scelerisque vitae, consequat in, pretium a, enim. Pellentesque congue. Ut in risus volutpat libero pharetra tempor. Cras vestibulum bibendum augue.

\vspace{5mm}\tikz \fill [white] (1,1) rectangle (2,5);
\vspace{3cm plus 1cm minus 1cm}
\end{exercise}

\begin{exercise}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed non risus. Suspendisse lectus tortor, dignissim sit amet, adipiscing nec, ultricies sed, dolor. Cras elementum ultrices diam. Maecenas ligula massa, varius a, semper congue, euismod non, mi. Proin porttitor, orci nec nonummy molestie, enim est eleifend mi, non fermentum diam nisl sit amet erat. Duis semper. Duis arcu massa, scelerisque vitae, consequat in, pretium a, enim. Pellentesque congue. Ut in risus volutpat libero pharetra tempor. Cras vestibulum bibendum augue.

\vspace{5mm}\tikz \fill [white] (1,1) rectangle (2,5);
\vspace{3cm plus 1cm minus 1cm}
\end{exercise}

\begin{exercise}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed non risus. Suspendisse lectus tortor, dignissim sit amet, adipiscing nec, ultricies sed, dolor. Cras elementum ultrices diam. Maecenas ligula massa, varius a, semper congue, euismod non, mi. Proin porttitor, orci nec nonummy molestie, enim est eleifend mi, non fermentum diam nisl sit amet erat. Duis semper. Duis arcu massa, scelerisque vitae, consequat in, pretium a, enim. Pellentesque congue. Ut in risus volutpat libero pharetra tempor. Cras vestibulum bibendum augue.

\vspace{5mm}\tikz \fill [white] (1,1) rectangle (2,5);
\vspace{3cm}
\end{exercise}

\begin{exercise}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed non risus. Suspendisse lectus tortor, dignissim sit amet, adipiscing nec, ultricies sed, dolor. Cras elementum ultrices diam. Maecenas ligula massa, varius a, semper congue, euismod non, mi. Proin porttitor, orci nec nonummy molestie, enim est eleifend mi, non fermentum diam nisl sit amet erat. Duis semper. Duis arcu massa, scelerisque vitae, consequat in, pretium a, enim. Pellentesque congue. Ut in risus volutpat libero pharetra tempor. Cras vestibulum bibendum augue.

\vspace{5mm}\tikz \fill [white] (1,1) rectangle (2,5);
\vspace{3cm}
\end{exercise}

\begin{exercise}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed non risus. Suspendisse lectus tortor, dignissim sit amet, adipiscing nec, ultricies sed, dolor. Cras elementum ultrices diam. Maecenas ligula massa, varius a, semper congue, euismod non, mi. Proin porttitor, orci nec nonummy molestie, enim est eleifend mi, non fermentum diam nisl sit amet erat. Duis semper. Duis arcu massa, scelerisque vitae, consequat in, pretium a, enim. Pellentesque congue. Ut in risus volutpat libero pharetra tempor. Cras vestibulum bibendum augue.

\vspace{5mm}\tikz \fill [white] (1,1) rectangle (2,5);
\vspace{3cm}
\end{exercise}
\end{document}
```

Many thanks in advance to your input!

Comment: You could try making some smaller boxes unbreakable and floating (float=t) if you really don't care about the order

Comment: Thanks for the idea, I'll try it asap. Would that work with hundreds of boxes? I guess at some point I'd run out of small boxes too...